# Read a file in AppController before the scene load

Tags: c#, android, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity3d. I have some settings which are stored in a file.

Currently I have a scene which has a game object which reads these settings in C# and this the settings are available everywhere, however 
I need these settings in 

1. iPhone=AppController (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) 

2. Android = onCreate

I am not sure how to call C# methods in this condition so as to have settings available when they are needed in iPhone (AppController) or Android (OnCreate).

Can somebody tell me how it can be done?

Thanks,
Ashwani

Comment: In android, there is a concept to store a file, along with the apk, which serves as a settings info to the app...and this could exist in in iOs aswell...

Comment: Actually, i have these setting stored in a file which are updated from server, it is sqlite database which is updated from server.

Comment: when ur porting apk to the actual device does this file move with that apk to device rit?

Comment: ok there should be a facility to have game configurations like screen size, no. of enemies, etc.. to be read from a file, on each game launch..this configuration file will go along the apk file(if this file doesn't exist on fresh installation,it should be created just like any file we create on windows...)....keeping this setting static or dynamic is the second half of the story...

Comment: Yea, as I said these settings come from server and saved in a file. The file reading logic in C# which is called when first scene is loaded. but there are some settings which are required in  iPhone (AppController) or Android (OnCreate) which is called before the scene launch. I am looking for a way to call C# method from iOS/Android.

Comment: If its hard to recreate file reading logic to particular platform specific, its better to start another question on "way to call C# method from iOS/Android"

Answer (score 0):

In iOS in AppController.m you could call a C# method by using

```
UnitySendMessage("Game_Object_Script_or_Name", "MethodName","Message");
```

From Unity in your Game_Object_Script_or_Name object's js or script file add:

```
function MethodName(Message:string) {

}
```

This sends messages from XCode to Your Unity Binary. To do it vice versa is trickier.

You need to write a native plugin. See the following (the bottom part is in Mandarin):

http://www.cnblogs.com/pengyingh/articles/2340812.html